# using Elixir's shorthand notation with multi-body anonymous functions

Tags: elixir

Given the Elixir function `add1 = fn a -> a + 1 end`, I know it is possible to express it in shorthand notation as `add1 = &(&1 + 1)`

Is there a way to use shorthand notation with multi-body functions?  For example the following function returns the greater of two numbers.

```
max = fn
  a, b when a > b -> a
  _a, b -> b
end
```

Is it possible to express this anonymous function using Elixir's shorthand notation?

Answer (score 1):

```
max = &
  case &1 > &2 do
    true -> &1
    false -> &2
  end
```

I would not consider this as a shorthand form though.

A generic solution would be put all arguments in a `case`:

```
max = &
  case {&1, &2} do
    {a, b} when a > b -> a
    {a, b} -> b
  end
```

But that would only make it longer.

Comment: This is shorthand but not multi-body. This can even be simplified to `&if(&1 > &2, do: &1, else: &2)`.

Comment: Or even `& &1 > &2 && &1 || &2`.

Comment: that gives wrong answer when both values are falsy but different: `max = & &1 > &2 && &1 || &2; max.(false, nil) == max.(nil, false) #=> false`.

Comment: From the answers so far, it appears there are shorthand notations for the function above using conditionals or logical operators, but no shorthand form to express it as a multi-body function.

Comment: @Kabie I am in chengdu too, can you leave you e-mail to me?

Answer (score 0):

This example works

```
max = fn
    (a, b) when a >= b -> a
    (_a, b) -> b
end

IO.puts max.(0, 2) # 2
IO.puts max.(2, -5) # 2
```

Comment: How is this "shorthand notation"?

Comment: I see you fixed the warning, I'll adjust the example above.